# RegEx to replace just part of the match

Tags: regex, vb.net, replace

Ive had a look in some similar topics but wasnt able to located what im looking for so im asking a new question.

**Is it possible to replace just a part of the string that matches the RegEx?**

For instance

I want to replace `00NN` to `+NN` . Just doing a simple replace on all `00` to `+` is not a option.

Below RegEx locates 2 zeros and 2 following numbers between 1-9.

```
Dim PhoneNumber AS String = Regex.Replace(IndexString, "([0][0][1-9]{2})", "+")
```

This replaces the entire `00NN` to `+`, if is possible to have the replace keep the following `NN` so it replaces `00NN` to `+NN`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there are two ways to do this:

1. Use a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) to store the part you want to keep:

   `Dim PhoneNumber AS String = Regex.Replace(IndexString, "\b00([1-9]{2})", "+$1")`

   Here, the parentheses capture the relevant part of the regex (they are numbered sequentially), and you can refer back to their contents in the replace string using `$1` for the match of the first group, `$2` for the second group etc. (and `$0` for the entire match).
2. Use a [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

   `Dim PhoneNumber AS String = Regex.Replace(IndexString, "\b00(?=[1-9]{2})", "+")`

   Here, `(?=...)` only asserts that it's *possible* to match `...` at the current position without actually making it part of the match. This solution is probably faster than the first solution.

One more thing: You should use a [word boundary anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) (`\b`) to make sure that you don't accidentally match `00` in the middle of a number - you probably don't want `00493010023456` to become `+49301+23456`, do you?

Comment: Thanks! The capturing group is very interesting, this will help me with other issues ;)

Comment: @KayNelson - though it might be disappointing to the first person, and we know Tim already has plenty of reputation as it is, if you think Tim's answer really is best, you should probably unselect the first selected answer and select Tim's (just make sure you upvote the first person's answer if it is still a good answer) - that way someone coming here later can see the best answer first.

Comment: @Tim - did you mean to use `preserve` instead of `conserve`? just a thought

Comment: @CodeJockey: Quite possibly :) I seem to have been using that word, thinking that it means something that it doesn't...

Comment: @TimPietzcker it is close in meaning... and most people wouldn't catch it, but it's not *quite* right, I don't think - maybe there's a Q&A [elsewhere in the network](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=preserve+conserve)

Answer (score 2):

You can use lookaheads to match only what you want:

```
Regex.Replace(IndexString, "00(?=[1-9]{2}))", "+")
```

The `(?=...)` is a zero width assertion that matches only if what's inside matches, so it will perform the check you want without selecting the `NN`.

Comment: Excellent! Worked perfect!